# How do I set compatible devices to only ARKit compatible devices in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, augmented-reality, arkit

How can I make sure my app on iOS AppStore only show compatibility for ARKit enabled devices only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key is `arkit` for your `info.plist` file under Required device capabilities.

[image]

[Apple documentation on plist keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) (UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities).

> **Key**: arkit
>
> **Description**: Include this key if your app requires support for ARKit
>   on the device (that is, an iOS device with an A9 or later processor).
>
> **Minimum version**: iOS 11.0

One important caveat for existing apps is that Apple does not allow you to restrict devices for an app once it has been released.

> Important: All device requirement changes must be made when you submit
>   an update to your binary. You are permitted only to expand your device
>   requirements. Submitting an update to your binary to restrict your
>   device requirements is not permitted. You are unable to restrict
>   device requirements because this action will keep customers who have
>   previously downloaded your app from running new updates.

If you are adding AR functionality to an existing application, you can use the [`isSupported`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/2923553-issupported) property of [ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit) to determine if you should expose this functionality.

Comment: Thanks, correct answer. Though It seems like Apple is currently allowing the arkit key to be included even after releasing the app. I included the arkit key to my existing app and App Store restricted my app from iPhone 4s to iPhoneSE/iPhone6S or greater. Worth mentioning is that my app is quite new and released on iOS11 release date.

Answer (score 0):

> If your app requires ARKit framework for its core functionality, then you need to open **`info.plist`** file (located inside your project's folder in macOS Finder) and under the key **`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilitie`** add a string **`arkit`** like that:

[image]

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
      <array>
        <string>arkit</string>
      </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

> But if Augmented Reality is a secondary feature of your app,
> then use this lines in `ViewController.swift`. Here's how your code should look like:

```
if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported {   
     
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()             // 6DOF
    configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
    sceneView.session.run(configuration) 

} else {  

    let configuration = AROrientationTrackingConfiguration()       // 3DOF
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)  
    print("This chipset does not meet the minimum requirements.")
}
```

A list of ARKit 4.0 compatible iPhones is the following (A9...A13 CPUs):

- iPhone 6s
- iPhone SE
- iPhone 7
- iPhone 8
- iPhone X
- iPhone SE2
- iPhone 11
- ...and higher