# prompt the user using a UIAlertController if iOS and device lower than iOS11 and iphone 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11

If a user installs up an application in a device lower than iPhone 8 and iOS version lower than iOS 11, a UI Alert pop" the minimum requirements to use the app is iOS 11 and iPhone 8 or above", and there is an ok button. I want to tell the user that is their device is not supported. Here is what I have in the code.

Note: I did set the deployment target to iOS11 but how can I set it for device iPhone8

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()       
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Foo", message: "Bar", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        // check
        if #available(iOS 11.0,*)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: "I want to the ok button to exit the application" Don't. Don't quit the app, it will be understand as a crash. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335848/exit-application-when-click-button-ios/

Comment: Since your deployment target is iOS 11 then you don't need any checks for iOS 11 since no one with iOS 10 will be able to install the app.

Comment: Why don't you want to support iPhone 7 or older? What about iPads (all iPhone-only apps can run on iPads).

Comment: You could use this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html but there is nothing that seems to block iPhone7 or lower. You should manage the cases. Why not iPhone 7?

Comment: @rmaddy it is one of the requirements the target device is iPhone 8 and OS iOS 11

Comment: But why? There are proper solutions but we need to know why so the correct answer can be given. And again, what about iPads?

Comment: ok I no need to hard code the iOS version check if I use the deployment target but what about the hardware

Comment: If we can't understand why you can't allow iPhone 7 or lower, its hard to tell, because as I link the Matrix, there seems to be no "discriminant" to avoid them. So it might be in fact a way to accept iPhone 7 and give you reason why/how (if you need to convince client/manager, etc.) Well, if you don't want to go on the AppStore and only in Private Enterprise Store, it should be okay though.

Comment: @rmaddy our System Archticter decided that we need to target iOS11 and iphone 8   and above iPad support come later and we target only in Private Enterprise Store

Comment: As I said, all iPhone apps run on iPads.

Comment: If this is for a private enterprise store, I guess you can get away with this, but in the public iTunes Store you can only restrict devices by restricting to libraries in info plist.  For example, ARKit.  If you're app using ARKIt, only supported on some devices, you can list this in your info plist and then only those devices can install the app.  However, you can not restrict devices once the app is live in production.  Here's a post about ARKit for example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569624/xcode-how-do-i-set-compatible-devices-to-only-arkit-compatible-devices

Comment: @rmaddy  for now, we are targeting iOS 11 we can do that using deployment target. our target device is iphone 8 and above no iPad support

Comment: Try this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/46234519/4311935 and you can use private APIs to check device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really, Really, REALLY (be sure) want to restrict usage of your app to iPhone 8 during runtime, you can read out the device model with this little extension to `UIDevice` from this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/9988514).

Beware, that Apple may not - or most likely will not - let you publish your app to the AppStore. Highly avoid killing the app by code!! Just show the alert, that your app is not designed to run on any device other than iPhone 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can require that the device support `nfc` in your `info.plist`.

Per Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

- nfc requires an iPhone 7 or higher and is unsupported across all iPads

[image]

[image]